# HTML5 AJAX Multiple Files Upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, file-upload

I came across this plain js ajax upload code (it seems that jquery `$.post` does not work with HTML5 for some reason),

```
    /* If you want to upload only a file along with arbitary data that
       is not in the form, use this */
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", document.getElementById('file').files[0]);

    /* If you want to simply post the entire form, use this */
    //var fd = document.getElementById('form1').getFormData();

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();        
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
    xhr.open("POST", "Upload.php");
    xhr.send(fd);
```

But I have two issues here,

1. what does this line mean after the object `FormData`?

`fd.append("file", document.getElementById('file').files[0]);`

Why do I need an ID there? Can I do something use jquery `append()`  with `$('input[type=file]')`?

1. This ajax is only for single file upload, how can I change it for multiple files upload?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> what does this line mean after the object FormData?
>
> ```
> fd.append("file", document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
> ```

The `document.getElementById('file')` gets the `<input type="file" id="file">` element by its ID. The `element.files[0]` grabs the first selected file from the element. The `fd.append("file", file)` appends it to an `FormData` instance with the field name of `file`. The `fd` is later to be sent as `multipart/form-data` XHR request body.

---

> Why do I need an ID there? Can I do something use jquery `append()` with `$('input[type=file]')`?

The ID is not necessary. It's after all just an example in order to be able to get the `<input type="file">` from the document by its ID. Note that the `append()` function in this example is part of [the `FormData` API](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-formdata-interface) and is not to be confused with jQuery's `append()` function. Also note that the 1st argument of `append()` represents the field name, not the ID. That they are the same is just a coincidence.

---

> *This ajax is only for single file upload, how can I change it for multiple files upload?*

Just append multiple fields to `FormData`. Assuming that you have a `File[]`, here's an example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { 
    fd.append("file" + i, files[i]);
}
```

It'll be available in the server end by the field names `file0`, `file1`, etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer! can I ask about this - `files.length` where does it the `files` come from? what should I set before this `for()` so I can do  `files.length`? thanks!

Comment: Uh, just get it from wherever the user has specified multiple files?

Comment: the first argument to `append` is not the _id_; it's the _name_, or _key_, of your key / value pair.

Comment: @aeo: that's correct. Did I tell otherwise? The `id="file"` is just mentioned because `document.getElementById()` couldn't otherwise select it.

Comment: Your post seems to imply that the first arg _is_ the id:

1 > It appends the currently selected `File` of an `<input type="file" id="file">`

you're implying that passing an arg of `file` will match an element of _id_ `file`

2 > The ID is not necessary.

you're implying that the first arg is the id

Comment: `The ID is not necessary.` still implies that the name is the id. I would correct the op asap: `the 1st arg is not the id; it represents the field name`.

Comment: If you use this method here, you can get the files server side in an array.
`for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { 
    fd.append("file[" + i + "]", files[i]);
}`

Comment: @sleeves: this is PHP-specific.

Comment: @BalusC I think you could parse file[0] just as easy as file0 in most server side scripts, right?  This way you get an advantage that helps in PHP and is no worse in other scripts.